# Anchor tag has half the link, but when I click on the link, it opens a new page with the complete link

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, href

To clarify what I mean. This is what the html looks like:

[image]

I am trying to fetch the href link from the highlighted part using this code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(r"http://wayback.archive.org/web/20101004060831/http://www.arcsoft.com:80/")

html = driver.page_source
page_soup = soup(html, "html.parser")

for i in page_soup.findAll("p", {"class": "impatient"}):
    print(i.a['href'])
```

The code returns `en-us/index.asp`which is not incorrect according to the program. But when I click on this href link in the page source, it redirects me to a website with a complete link.

This is the final URL of the website: http://web.archive.org/web/20100227101719/http://www.arcsoft.com/en-us/index.asp

Can anyone please help me on how can I get this complete URL?

Comment: Add `a["href"]` to link? `http://web.archive.org/web/20100227101719/http://www.arcsoft.com/ + a["href"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can *[explicitly](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits)* wait for the error message page and then wait for the final page to load. The error page has a *div* with *id* `error`. The Final page will always have an *div* with *id* `siteWrapper`. You can also handle cases in which there is no error page using TimeoutException.

From the documentation:

> If
>   nothing is found after that time, a`TimeoutException` is thrown. By
>   default, WebDriverWait calls the ExpectedCondition every 500
>   milliseconds until it returns successfully. A successful return value
>   for the ExpectedCondition function type is a Boolean value of true, or
>   a non-null object.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
# Get the first page
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/path/to/chromedriver")
driver.get(r"http://wayback.archive.org/web/20101004060831/http://www.arcsoft.com:80/")
try:
    # Wait for Error Page
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="error"]')))
except TimeoutException:
    # Pass if there is no error message
    pass
# Wait for new page
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="siteWrapper"]')))
print(driver.current_url)
```

Output

```
http://web.archive.org/web/20100227101719/http://www.arcsoft.com/en-us/index.asp
```

Now `driver.page_source` will get the page source of the final page.

There is no need to manually calculate the new url and then go to that page.